# ¿Cómo le pongo una luz neon a la silueta de una imagen png la cual no tiene fondo?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo una imagen en formato png, la cual tiene fondo transparente. Al momento de crear el efecto de luz neón en HTML y CSS, solo se resalta el borde, quedando rectangular la imagen y sin que quede la silueta de la imagen. ¿Cómo hago para solamente resaltar la silueta de la imagen al pasar por encima de ella y que no se resalte todo el rectángulo de la imagen?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

En resumen pon como lo tienes ahora para tomar la base y ayudarte.

Comment: Si estas aplicando el efecto en la propiedad de css `border` siempre lo va a aplicar al área total de la imagen porque esa es realmente la imagen, no hay forma de aplicarlo solo al perímetro del objeto sin fondo en la imagen. CSS no puede reconocer lo que hay dentro de la imagen. Lo mejor sería crear otra imagen igual pero ya con el borde y solo intercambia entre una y otra cuando pases por encima. Si fuera una imagen vectorial probablemente si pudieras hacerlo como svg

Comment: Muchas gracias (! mes tarde pero lo vale), me ayudó mucho para configurarlo y funciona full.